# What were these CYOA-style books?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, books

In the (late?) '80s I "played" some books. They were choose-your-own-adventure-like, but with a big caveat: there was a character sheet (within the first few pages, or maybe the inside of the front cover?) where you would track some things that changed through the course of the adventure: HP, spells you knew, maybe AC when you found some gear? Through the book/adventure you would have choices at the end of a page, but some of them would depend on your current state.

They were D&D-like (fantasy adventure), though I can't swear they were by TSR. I do remember pretty vividly *spider climb* being a spell I used, though....

Any chance this rings a bell for you?

Comment: I don't *think* it's Tunnels and Trolls solo books, based on reading the WP entry, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The [Lone Wolf fantasy gamebooks](https://www.projectaon.org/en/Main/Books) worked this way, but I don't think that was it, as there was no _spider climb_ spell that I can find. There was a Magnakai discipline of Huntmastery which allowed improved climbing, though nothing named _spider climb_.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard There was also a miniseries set in the same world focusing on Grey Star the Wizard, but magic was divided into broader *kinds* of magic like prophecy, sorcery, etc. I don't think there were any individual spells mentioned.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard thanks for the pointer. At this point (thirty-plus years later) I'm not sure I *really* trust my own memory, so I'll probably pick up one of the LW books you mention just to check the feel.

Comment: I think I still have one, but they came as a set and I lost the companion book.

Comment: I know exactly what you're talking about OP, but I can't recall the name. I'll look for it (I may still have one around somewhere), but I'm fairly certain they weren't TSR and you're not crazy.

Answer (score 19):

##### Most likely answer: *Super Endless Quest* aka *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons Adventure Gamebooks*

The [**Super Endless Quest**](https://gamebooks.org/Series/21/Show) series, later renamed **Advanced Dungeons & Dragons Adventure Gamebooks**, contains all the elements you remember (Thanks to [Astrid_Redfern](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/61604/astrid-redfern) for pointing this out!).

---

##### Other possibilities

Given the character sheet elements, you might be referring to [the **Fighting Fantasy** series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy), by Steve Jackson and Ian Livingstone. They weren't set in D&D universes, and were not licensed by TSR, but they did typically use a fantasy theme.

The other possibility is that you're remembering [the predecessor to **Super Endless Quest**, **Endless Quest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Quest), originally released under TSR and set in generic D&D universes, but eventually expanding to other settings, continuing publication under WotC. It didn't have character sheets or dice rolling, being essentially a rebranded Choose Your Own Adventure in generic D&D settings, but it's close.

If you're not remembering **Super Endless Quest**, you could be mixing memories of multiple series; the character sheets and die rolling were **Fighting Fantasy**, while the strongly D&D elements like actual spells pulled straight from D&D like *spider climb* were from **Endless Quest**.

Comment: @nitsua60: Yeah, I just updated the answer because I missed the character sheet aspect. My guess is you mixed up memories of both, because the Fighting Fantasy series (which had character sheets and dice rolling) was not D&D licensed, while Endless Quest was. Dragon of Doom (the one I own) was a weird one, in that it pretended to have a limited resource element given to your character, but you could never use it up (so no resource tracking was actually involved).

Comment: Fighting Fantasy looks like a possibility... I'll pick one up and see if it conjures memories. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowRanger There was a series called [Super Endless Quest](https://gamebooks.org/Series/21/Show), which was intended as a more advanced successor to [*Endless Quest*](https://gamebooks.org/Series/79/Show) that older players could pick up. In describing the series, Demian states that it DID have: *"attribute scores ... added to dice rolls to determine success or failure in various actions during the book. There are also hit points to keep track of, and some books feature experience points (which can be spent to modify dice rolls), spellcasting, or other special rules."*

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern: Oh, man, can't believe I missed those. I've edited the answer to add and prioritize that (with credit to you), since it's much closer to what the OP remembered. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

An excellent reference is [Damien's Gamebook Site](https://gamebooks.org/Publisher/26/Show).

There were a number of gamebooks produced by TSR. The only one I played was the Druid vs Mage one, which could also be played solo. They had D&D style character sheets in them. These were part of the 1 on 1 Adventure series.

Your book is probably in the Advanced Dungeons & Dragons Adventure Gamebooks series, which started off as Super Endless Quest.

A likely candidate for what you want is [Sceptre of Power](https://gamebooks.org/Item/135/Show), book one in the *Kingdom of Sorcery Trilogy*.

A copy of the inset can be seen [here](https://archive.org/details/ad-d-adventure-gamebooks-clash-of-the-sorcerers/AD%26D%20Adventure%20Gamebooks%20Sceptre%20of%20Power/page/n1/mode/2up): it has Hit Points and Spider Climb.

In case the inset link doesn't work:

[image: Character stats card]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Ooh, wow. Definitely will pick up one or more of these and see if they knock anything loose from the dusty, old grey-matter filing cabinets. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Could this possibly be [Wizards, Warriors, and You](https://www.goodreads.com/series/96855-wizards-warriors-and-you), a series from the mid-80s by RL Stine? You choose between reading as the Wizard (with spells) or the Warrior (with equipment).

Comment: Do those have character sheets as explained by OP?

Comment: As the warrior, you would choose a weapons loadout.  As the wizard, you would choose spells.  Other than that, no.

Comment: @BenBarden Then that doesn't seem like a relevant answer.